# Is there a way to match a specific pattern within curly braces multiple times using regex?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, notepad++

I use an older language that doesn't have any prebuilt syntax highlighters.

Although notepad++ has user defined language features there are some cases that aren't supported. For these cases I use a python script that applies syntax highlighting using regex.

My current issue I have run into is using regex to find patterns within curly braces. The pattern I'm trying to match is `[A-Za-z_]\w*` . 
So basically, a variable name. However I would like to match only instances that occur within double curly braces.

In the following string I would like to match both instances of `TimeStamps` and `Descending` and nothing else.
`Test Test2'{{TimeStamps(Descending(1))(7:8)}}/{{TimeStamps(Descending(1))(1:4)}} - '`

I have tried variations of this `(?<={{)([A-Za-z_]\w*)*(?=[0-9\(\)\:]*}})`, however it feels like I'm over complicating it for myself.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the pattern for python or for notepad? You might use capturing groups `{{(\w+)[^\(]*\(([^()]+).*?}}` https://regex101.com/r/PCvoDi/1

Comment: Use `{{.*?}}` and then get each match inside the previous matches with your `[A-Za-z_]\w*`

Comment: Unfortunately, python is just the vehicle that I'm using to feed the regex strings into notepad++. There's a library which takes a regex string and a color and it applies that color to all matches.

Comment: So, what is the input, and expected output? Do you have access to Python code? Can you use PyPi `regex` module rather than `re`?

Comment: I'm not using `re`. I'm sending a raw string and an RGB color to a notepad++ library and having it do the work for me. https://regex101.com/r/6jxkfz/1 Here is the expected output. However that is way more complex than I want it and only supports 2 variables.

Comment: Not sure what is supported, but perhaps try `(?:{{(?=(?:(?!(?:{{|}})).)*}})|\G(?!^))(?:\(?\K[A-Za-z_]\w*(?=\())` https://regex101.com/r/TlWMOs/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird That is really close but there are cases where it doesn't work. Example: `'{{ListHeight + 4}}, {{(ListWidth / 2) + 0.5}}, cc 6, '`. I should mention that these are essentially like python's Fstrings and any variable or math operation can be placed inside them.

Comment: Or without the lookahead https://regex101.com/r/B8OtSz/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird There are still a few edge cases where it fails. But those are easy enough to stamp out with additional regexes. If you post that as an answer with an explanation I'll accept it.

Comment: Try a workaround, `[A-Za-z_]\w*(?=(?:(?!{{|}}).)*}})` (or ``[A-Za-z_]\w*(?=(?:(?!{{|}})[\s\S])*}})``)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I've been using it ever since and it works perfectly! Although there was one caveat I failed to mention. It also needs to not match any strings, however I just applied another string matching regex immediately afterwards and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
\b[A-Za-z_]\w*(?=(?:(?!{{|}}).)*}})
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jNtc6l/1/)

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `[A-Za-z_]` - an ASCII letter or `_`
- `\w*` - any 0 or more word chars (letters, digits or  `_`)
- `(?=(?:(?!{{|}}).)*}})` - a positive lookahead that requires

  - `(?:(?!{{|}}).)*` - any char, 0 or more occurrences, other than line break chars, that does not start a `{{` or `}}` substring (it is a [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970))
  - `}}` - a `}}` substring.

Answer (score 1):

You could use your pattern to match the variable by first matching `{{` and then assert that there is a closing `}}` present without matching `{{` in between.

```
(?:{{(?=[^{}]*(?:{(?!{)|}(?:!}))*}})|\G(?!^))\(?\K[A-Za-z_]\w*
```

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `{{` Match literally
  - `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is

    - `[^{}]*` Match 0+ occurrences of any char except `{` or `}`
    - `(?:{(?!{)|}(?:!}))*` If there is `{` or `}` assert it is not followed by the same char
    - `}}` Match literally
  - `)` Close lookahead
  - `|` Or
- `\G(?!^)` Assert the position at the end of the previous match
- `)` Close group
- `\(?\K` match optional `(` and forget what is currently matched
- `[A-Za-z_]\w*` Pattern to match the varialbe

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/B74lLG/1)

Comment: I just want to mention that this one `[A-Za-z_]\w*(?=(?:(?!{{|}}).)*}})` works perfectly for my use case. Thanks so much for all your time.

Comment: @Axe319 You are welcome. It is certainly a good pattern but I think that it will also match without the opening double curly's `ListHeight + 4}}` You could ask @WiktorStribiżew to post it as an answer and accept his if the pattern works better for your use case.